# kinect virtual machine

Tags: ros, kinect, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Does anyone know how to have it correctly configured.
I found these 2 blogs which basically say the same thing:
http://blog.justsophie.com/installing-kinect-nite-drivers-on-ubuntu-14-04-and-ros-indigo/
http://www.20papercups.net/programming/kinect-on-ubuntu-with-openni/
Except when it is run i get the following output:

> ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311
>
> core service [/rosout] found
> process[camera/camera_nodelet_manager-1]: started with pid [9197]
> process[camera/driver-2]: started with pid [9198]
> process[camera/rgb_debayer-3]: started with pid [9199]
> process[camera/rgb_rectify_mono-4]: started with pid [9200]
> process[camera/rgb_rectify_color-5]: started with pid [9212]
> process[camera/ir_rectify_ir-6]: started with pid [9226]
> process[camera/depth_rectify_depth-7]: started with pid [9239]
> process[camera/depth_metric_rect-8]: started with pid [9247]
> process[camera/depth_metric-9]: started with pid [9262]
> process[camera/depth_points-10]: started with pid [9269]
> process[camera/register_depth_rgb-11]: started with pid [9280]
> process[camera/points_xyzrgb_sw_registered-12]: started with pid [9290]
> process[camera/depth_registered_sw_metric_rect-13]: started with pid [9298]
> process[camera/depth_registered_rectify_depth-14]: started with pid [9305]
> process[camera/points_xyzrgb_hw_registered-15]: started with pid [9317]
> process[camera/depth_registered_hw_metric_rect-16]: started with pid [9332]
> process[camera/depth_registered_metric-17]: started with pid [9336]
> process[camera/disparity_depth-18]: started with pid [9351]
> process[camera/disparity_registered_sw-19]: started with pid [9361]
> process[camera/disparity_registered_hw-20]: started with pid [9376]
> process[camera_base_link-21]: started with pid [9381]
> process[camera_base_link1-22]: started with pid [9393]
> process[camera_base_link2-23]: started with pid [9409]
> process[camera_base_link3-24]: started with pid [9421]
> [ INFO] [1475754659.014660672]: Initializing nodelet with 4 worker threads.
> Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...
> Warning: USB events thread - failed to set priority. This might cause loss of data...

> [ INFO] [1475754661.349678945]: Number devices connected: 1

> [ INFO] [1475754661.350816379]: 1. device on bus 001:18 is a SensorKinect (2ae) from PrimeSense (45e) with serial id 'A00366A03094046A'

> [ INFO] [1475754661.353426645]: Searching for device with index = 1

> [ INFO] [1475754661.873200396]: Opened 'SensorKinect' on bus 1:18 with serial number 'A00366A03094046A'

> [ INFO] [1475754661.932177037]: rgb_frame_id = 'camera_rgb_optical_frame'

> [ INFO] [1475754661.932592992]: depth_frame_id = 'camera_depth_optical_frame'

> [ WARN] [1475754661.938842439]: Camera calibration file /home/gijs/.ros/camera_info/rgb_A00366A03094046A.yaml not found.

> [ WARN] [1475754661.939210597]: Using default parameters for RGB camera calibration.

> [ WARN] [1475754661.939919751]: Camera calibration file /home/gijs/.ros/camera_info/depth_A00366A03094046A.yaml not found.

> [ WARN] [1475754661.940174503]: Using default parameters for IR camera calibration.

It says it started but when using rostopic no messages will be published. Does anyone know how to fix this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245114/kinect-virtual-machine/) by [gijsje170](https://answers.ros.org/users/25135/gijsje170/) on ROS Answers with karma: 171 on 2016-10-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Are you using virtual machines for installing ROS?

I tried using VMs for ROS but they often don't function correctly.

I would suggest **using a real PC install for ROS**.

---

Originally posted by [joe_cheng](https://answers.ros.org/users/28175/joe_cheng/) with karma: 61 on 2016-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1